# Android: how to divide one activity into two separate activities?

Tags: android

I want to divide my one activity into two separate ones but, I want that they be on the same screen..
If I explained not very clearly, I attach pictures of what I mean - [image: here is the image]

so please help me with this question

Comment: Try Fragment Activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably want to look at [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this very simple introduction into fragments: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzqIOzOkVVw

Comment: nice it is very usefull!

Answer (score 0):

You should use fragments in android. Two fragments within same activity will do what you want above.